# How can I check if a page was reached via jQuery Mobile's back button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm working on a jQuery page and I want to know if the page was reached via the user's "back" button (the one in jQuery mobile (`data-rel="back"`), not the browser back button).

I have done a bit of web searching and reading through jqm's site, but no joy.

Comment: hm. thats not a bad idea. i was hoping that there was a built in way to check for this though through jqm that i just didnt know about. i'll likely end up going with that if nothing else. feel free to type it up as an answer just in case (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the callback `state.direction`

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s5t3P/)

[*more info here*](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.navigate/)

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (evt, data) {
  var backForw = data.state.direction;
  if (backForw) {
     console.log("Button "+ backForw +" was used");
  }
});
```

Or, if you want you can store a flag into `localStorage` and check for it's existence or using JS's `pushState`...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: That's perfect for what I need. Thanks a lot buddy.